# why peek doesn't run in a parallel stream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, stream

The following is my code fragment, the result always show:

```
main sort3 
main sort3 
main sort3 
main sort3
```

The peek after sorted seems like not running. Have you ever met this kind of weird thing?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Random random = new Random();

    Stream<Integer> parallel = Stream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(1000))   
            .limit(10)    

            .sorted((a, b) -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sort3 ");
                return a.compareTo(b);
            })                 //3
            .peek(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " peek4 " + i))  //4
            .peek(i-> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" peek5 " + i))   //5
            .parallel().count();

    Thread.sleep(20000);

}
```

Comment: _"In cases where the stream implementation is able to optimize away the production of some or all the elements (such as with short-circuiting operations like findFirst, **or in the example described in [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count())**), the action will not be invoked for those elements."_, from [`Stream.peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)).

Comment: Thanks.   You are correct.  I added .filter(i->i>400)  after sorted .  the two peeks began to run .     Stream is smart and sophiscated,  but somewhat confusing .....